# How do I mock AWS SDK (v2) with rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, aws-sdk-ruby

I have a class which reads/processes messages from an SQS queue using [the aws-sdk-rails gem](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-rails) (which is a wrapper on [aws-sdk-ruby v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby)).  How do I mock the AWS calls so I can test my code without hitting the external services?

**communicator.rb**:

```
class Communicator
  def consume_messages
    sqs_client = Aws::SQS::Client.new
    # consume messages until the queue is empty
    loop do
      r = sqs_client.receive_message({
                                              queue_url: "https://sqs.region.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/foo",
                                              visibility_timeout: 1,
                                              max_number_of_messages: 1
                                     })
      break if (response.message.length == 0)
      # process r.messages.first.body
      r = sqs_client.delete_message({
                                      queue_url: "https://sqs.region.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/foo",
                                      receipt_handle: r.messages.first.receipt_handle
                                    })
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This older question addresses the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380426/how-to-mock-aws-sdk-gem. But well, it is about stubbing, not mocking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a hard time finding examples mocking AWS resources.  I spent a few days figuring it out and wanted to share my results on Stack Overflow for posterity.  I used [rspec-mocks](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs) ([doubles](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/test-doubles) & [verifying doubles)](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/verifying-doubles).  Here's an example with the `communicator.rb` example in the question.

**communicator_spec.rb**:

```
RSpec.describe Communicator do
  describe "#consume_messages" do
    it "can use rspec doubles & verifying doubles to mock AWS SDK calls" do
      sqs_client = instance_double(Aws::SQS::Client)
      allow(Aws::SQS::Client).to receive(:new).and_return(sqs_client)
      SQSResponse = Struct.new(:messages)
      SQSMessage = Struct.new(:body, :receipt_handle)
      response = SQSResponse.new([SQSMessage.new(File.read('data/expected_body.json'), "receipt_handle")])
      empty_response = SQSResponse.new([])
      allow(sqs_client).to receive(:receive_message).
                            and_return(response, empty_response)
      allow(sqs_client).to receive(:delete_message).and_return(nil)

      Communicator.new.consume_messages
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can also do that with:           `allow_any_instance_of(AWS::SQS::Client).to receive(:receive_message).and_return(response, empty_response) `

Comment: After trying to overwrite the class, using `class_doubles`, and wayyyy too much time - this is the only way I could find that will not give you double leaking problems and all around just works. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

The AWS SDK already provides stubbing. q.v. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ClientStubs.html for more information (Linked to official documentation.)

Comment: [The link for SDK v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/ClientStubs.html)